# In which cases angular directive scope equals controller scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple directive without scope definition:

```
angularModule.directive('sizer', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {      
        }
    }
});
```

There is NO "scope" definition in this directive.

this directive is included in a view:

```
<div sizer></div>
```

Usually the scope in this directive equals controller's scope. But sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes the directive's scope is a child scope of the controller. In which cases is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directives in Angularjs has 3 scopes , as mentioned below

- `scope:false`  :  does not create any new scopes , uses the parent scope  (controller's scope) , which is by default .
- `scope:true`   : does create a new child scope , which prototypically inherit from the parent scope (controller's scope).
- `scope:{}` : isolate scope ,which doesnt inherit from the parent scope which has bindable properties to parent's scope using '@' , '=' , '&'

refer : **[scopes in angualrjs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)**

Answer (score 1):

When use `scope` true it inherit from parent while use `scope` empty object it make new isolated scope

```
angularModule.directive('sizer', function () {
    return {
      scope: true,  // use a child scope that inherits from parent   
      restrict: 'EA',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {      
        }
    }
});

angularModule.directive('sizer', function () {
    return {
      scope: {},  // use a new isolated scope
      restrict: 'EA',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {      
        }
    }
});
```